# Scrape gmail for selected content and get attachments

Tags: python-3.x, smtp, gmail, imap

I have a problem to scrape gmail.
Candidates should extract or pull information relating to financial transactions from Gmail. The information could be invoices, subscription alerts, bills, etc. We want you to connect with a Gmail account and scrape or pull data of invoices, subscriptions, upcoming bills. You can scrape the emails for words like upcoming invoice or subscription or invoice etc and pull the
amount, date, attachment if any all these details.

I have to collect information and also store all the attachments. Is there any specific simple way to do it?

my Code

```
import imaplib
import os
import email, getpass
import sys
import json

class GmailFinin():
    def helloWorld(self):
        print("\nHello I'm here to help you")

    def initializeVariables(self):
        self.usr = ""
        self.pwd = ""
        self.mail = object
        self.mailbox = ""
        self.mailCount = 0
        self.destFolder = ""
        self.data = []
        self.ids = []
        self.idsList = []

    def getLogin(self):
        print("\nPlease enter your Gmail login details below.")
        self.usr = input("Email: ")
        # self.pwd = input("Password: ")
        self.pwd = getpass.getpass("Enter your password --> ")

    def attemptLogin(self):
        self.mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
        if self.mail.login(self.usr, self.pwd):
            print("\nLogon SUCCESSFUL")
            self.destFolder = input("\nPlease choose a destination folder in the form of /Users/username/dest/ (do not forget trailing slash!): ")
            if not self.destFolder.endswith("/"): self.destFolder+="/"
            return True
        else:
            print("\nLogon FAILED")
            return False

    def checkIfUsersWantsToContinue(self):
        print("\nWe have found "+str(self.mailCount)+" emails in the mailbox "+self.mailbox+".")
        return True if input("Do you wish to continue extracting all the emails into "+self.destFolder+"? (y/N) ").lower().strip()[:1] == "y" else False       
        
    def selectMailbox(self):
        # self.mailbox = input("\nPlease type the name of the mailbox you want to extract, e.g. Inbox: ")
        self.mailbox = "Inbox"
        bin_count = self.mail.select(self.mailbox)[1]
        self.mailCount = int(bin_count[0].decode("utf-8"))
        return True if self.mailCount > 0 else False

    def searchThroughMailbox(self):
        type, self.data = self.mail.search(None, "ALL")
        self.ids = self.data[0]
        self.idsList = self.ids.split()

    def parseEmails(self):
        jsonOutput = {}
        for anEmail in self.data[0].split():
            type, self.data = self.mail.fetch(anEmail, '(UID RFC822)')
            raw = self.data[0][1]
            try:
                raw_str = raw.decode("utf-8")
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                try:
                    raw_str = raw.decode("ISO-8859-1") # ANSI support
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    try:
                        raw_str = raw.decode("ascii") # ASCII ?
                    except UnicodeDecodeError:
                        pass
                        
            msg = email.message_from_string(raw_str)

            jsonOutput['subject'] = msg['subject']
            jsonOutput['from'] = msg['from']
            jsonOutput['date'] = msg['date']
            
            raw = self.data[0][0]
            raw_str = raw.decode("utf-8")


            uid = raw_str.split()[2]
            # Body #
            if msg.is_multipart():
                for part in msg.walk():
                    partType = part.get_content_type()
                    ## Get Body ##
                    if partType == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in part:
                        jsonOutput['body'] = part.get_payload()
                    ## Get Attachments ##
                    if part.get('Content-Disposition') is not None:
                        attchName = part.get_filename()
                        print(attchName)
                        if bool(attchName):
                            attchFilePath = str(self.destFolder)+str(uid)+str("/")+str(attchName)
                            print(attchFilePath)
                            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(attchFilePath), exist_ok=True)
                            with open(attchFilePath, "wb") as f:
                                f.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            else:
                # jsonOutput['body'] = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode("utf-8") # Non-multipart email, perhaps no attachments or just text.
                jsonOutput['body'] = msg.get_payload()


            outputDump = json.dumps(jsonOutput)
            emailInfoFilePath = str(self.destFolder)+str(uid)+str("/")+str(uid)+str(".json")
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(emailInfoFilePath), exist_ok=True)
            print(emailInfoFilePath)
            with open(emailInfoFilePath, "w") as f:
                f.write(outputDump)

    def __init__(self):
        self.initializeVariables()
        self.helloWorld()
        self.getLogin()
        if self.attemptLogin():
            not self.selectMailbox() and sys.exit()
        else:
            sys.exit()
        not self.checkIfUsersWantsToContinue() and sys.exit()
        self.searchThroughMailbox()
        self.parseEmails()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run = GmailFinin()
```

I have tried using below for search, but I don't think i.e optimal because it is searching only in subject and How to add multiple or condition for list of keywords.

```
                type, self.data = self.mail.search(None, '(OR TEXT "bill" SUBJECT "bill")')
```

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. What is the issue with your current solution?

Comment: The issue is how do I get only email that contain specific words related to finance such as invoice, bill, amount etc. Currently I'm able to read all mails and attachments but unable to search only finance related keyword emails.

Comment: You appear to be going though the SMTP server i dont think mail servers have the ability to search.  Your probably going to have to parse that locally after scanning all their emails.   Have you tried testing this with someone that has 2fa enabled on their gmail account?

Comment: I'm new to this, I found good doc to play with scrap the mail so I studied it and created my code. But now I'm stuck into getting only those email that are in list of keywords such as `['invoice','bills','subscription alert']` and fetch total amount from it. If you have any better solution for it, I would love to learn it from you.

Comment: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools